# count leading zeros (clz) or number of leading zeros (nlz) in Java

Tags: java, binary, converters

I need `int 32` in binary as `00100000` or `int 127` in binary `0111 1111`.
The variant `Integer.toBinaryString` returns results only from 1.
If I build the for loop this way:

```
for (int i= 32; i <= 127; i + +) {
System.out.println (i); 
System.out.println (Integer.toBinaryString (i));
}
```

And from binary numbers I need the number of leading zeros (count leading zeros (clz) or number of leading zeros (nlz)) I really meant the exact number of 0, such ex: at 00100000 -> 2 and at 0111 1111 - > 1

Comment: Consider _formatting_ the output so as to put leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the number of leading zeros as follows:

```
int lz = 8;
while (i)
{
    lz--;
    i >>>= 1;
}
```

Of course, this supposes the number doesn't exceed 255, otherwise, you would get negative results.

Comment: This approach is very slow as it creates a temporary String object. Using Integer methods is the recommended approach.

Comment: @antiguru: After seeing this almost two year later, I decided that I must change it. This was too horrible.

Answer (score 11):

How about

```
int lz = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i & 0xFF) - 24;
int tz = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i | 0x100); // max is 8.
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficient solution is int ans = 8-(log<sub>2</sub>(x)+1)

you can calculate log<sub>2</sub>(x)= log<sub>y</sub> (x) / log<sub>y</sub> (2)

Comment: This solution is almost equal to the solution given by @Martijn Courteaux,  log<sub>2</sub>(x) gives you the length of the binaryString(x) without leading zeros. so 8 - lengthOfString_WithoutLeadingZeroes gives your answer

Comment: What do you mean, the correct solution for 32 is 3, its working right!

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice that binary counting starts with pow(2,0) , so subtract one from the answer, and the answer should be strictly integer and do not round it off.

Comment: What an excellent answer! I would upvote multiple times if I could. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UtilsInt {

    int leadingZerosInt(int i) {
        return leadingZeros(i,Integer.SIZE);
    }

    /**
     * use recursion to find occurence of first set bit
     * rotate right by one bit & adjust complement
     * check if rotate value is not zero if so stop counting/recursion
     * @param i - integer to check 
     * @param maxBitsCount - size of type (in this case int)
     *                       if we want to check only for:
     *                         positive values we can set this to Integer.SIZE / 2   
     *                         (as int is signed  in java - positive values are in L16 bits)
     */
     private synchronized int leadingZeros(int i, int maxBitsCount) {
         try {
            logger.debug("checking if bit: "+ maxBitsCount 
                                + " is set | " + UtilsInt.intToString(i,8));
            return (i >>>= 1) != 0 ? leadingZeros(i, --maxBitsCount) : maxBitsCount;
         } finally {
             if(i==0) logger.debug("bits in this integer from: " + --maxBitsCount 
                               + " up to last are not set (i'm counting from msb->lsb)");
         }
    }
}
```

test statement:

```
int leadingZeros = new UtilsInt.leadingZerosInt(255); // 8
```

test output:

```
checking if bit: 32 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
checking if bit: 31 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 01111111
checking if bit: 30 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 00111111
checking if bit: 29 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 00011111
checking if bit: 28 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111
checking if bit: 27 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111
checking if bit: 26 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
checking if bit: 25 is set |00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
bits in this integer from: 24 up to last are not set (i'm counting from msb->lsb)
```