# Bit numbering - find first set (ffs) or find first one (ffo) Java

Tags: java, bit

```
for (int i = 32; i <= 127; i++) {
}
```

I convert the number `int 32` into binary number `00100000` and the number `int 127` into binary `01111111`. I need the first position of one read from right (Bit numbering - find first set (ffs) or find first one (ffo)), 00100000 -> `6` and at 01111111 -> `1`

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API is your friend too :

```
static int position(int a){
    int pos = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(a);
    return pos == 32 ? -1 : pos;
}
```

Comment: @user3235117 You can do `int pos = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(a)+1; return pos == 33 ? -1 : pos;`. This is just a matter of taste (bit at position 0th or not). Usually, the convention is to say that the first bit is at position 0.

Comment: @user3235117 if you only have a byte instead of an int I suggest you have a look at the answer I gave when you asked this question before http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351222/57695

Comment: @ZouZou can you briefly explain why `pos == 32 ? -1 : pos` and how to get to the result? I want to understand. Thank you!

Comment: @user3235117 What don't you understand? The syntax?

Comment: @user3235117 This is the same as `if(pos == 32) return -1; else return pos;` This is called conditional operator : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Thank you! I'm studying computer of science only in the first semester

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of finding this number is as follows:

```
int findLowestSetBit(int n) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 32 ; i++) {
        if ((n & (1 << i)) != 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

However, it is not the fastest one, because it searches for a set bit "linearly". You can do it in parallel with the following piece of code [copied from the bit hack page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightParallel):

```
int v;      // 32-bit word input to count zero bits on right
int c = 32; // c will be the number of zero bits on the right
v &= -v;
if (v != 0) c--;
if ((v & 0x0000FFFF) != 0) c -= 16;
if ((v & 0x00FF00FF) != 0) c -= 8;
if ((v & 0x0F0F0F0F) != 0) c -= 4;
if ((v & 0x33333333) != 0) c -= 2;
if ((v & 0x55555555) != 0) c -= 1;
```

Comment: To turn this code into Java, you will need to say `if ((v & ....) != 0)` instead of just `if (v & ....)`, as Java requires `if` conditions to be `boolean` rather than `int`.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; 
  expected
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; 
  expected

Answer (score 0):

to find a [leading zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_zero) you can use recursion & [bit wise shift](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

i post answer to similar question here:

[count leading zeros (clz) or number of leading zeros (nlz) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350827/count-leading-zeros-clz-or-number-of-leading-zeros-nlz-in-java/38055625#38055625)

or using a [Divine & Conquer Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) which some examples are here :

[How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)